# Set div with text to start where another div that is positioned center starts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've got some text that is positioned center of the container and I would like to have some other text that starts where the text positioned in center starts (these divs are not having the same length so here is the problem) I tried by adding jquery to get the X position but no success, and I have no clue how to solve it only with css.

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="graphic-icons-page">
    <div class="container icons-container">
    <div class="icons-software-title-left">Wide</div>
      <div class="icons-software-title-center text-center"><span>Text in center</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.icons-container{
  height:80vh;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
 
  
  
}
.graphic-icons-page{  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center}

  ///test 

.icons-software-title-center{
  width: 100%;
}
.icons-software-title-left{ font-size: 50px;}
.icons-software-title-center{
  font-size:50px
}
```

Here's how I want to look:

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you mean you want the next sentence to start where the word "Wide" and "Text" start? Can you maybe put a picture how you want it to look like?

Comment: Basically "text in ceter of the page" it's already positioned in center of the page, and I would like "Wide" to start where "Text " starts

Comment: The photo is what I want to obtain (sorry for misunderstanding)

Comment: I tested your code on jsfiddler and seems like it's already starting just how you want it to be: https://jsfiddle.net/x2yu8cvg/ Unless you also want it to be centered vertically?

Comment: Thats because on fiddle icons-container width is not defined but I will do the same in my code thank you

Comment: Still I am not sure about it

Comment: Can you update the css based on what you actually have? Is `.icons-container` supposed to have a fixed width?

Comment: The code is the same but the issues is that on fiddle is not updated with Bootstrap so container class is not updating it. Considering that I will have some content after this it's mandatory to keep this in the container. So I gotta find a way to maintain icon-container width even if it's in container class of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I added one div and move the icons-container inside the other container. Would this work?

In this fiddle, I added bootstrap css to test https://jsfiddle.net/1aywg3Lm/

```css
body {

   background-color: black;

}
.container-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.icons-container{
  height:80vh;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
.graphic-icons-page{  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center}

  ///test 

.icons-software-title-center{
  width: 100%;
}
.icons-software-title-left{ font-size: 20px;}
.icons-software-title-center{
  font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<div class="graphic-icons-page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="icons-container">
        <div class="icons-software-title-left">Wide</div>
        <div class="icons-software-title-center text-center"><span>Text in center of the page</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues using `width:max-content`

```
.container-center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
.icons-container{
  height:80vh;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: max-content;


}
```